# Overriding Bootstrap with using my external stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap and wanted to make an exercise by building this site on my own:
https://konect.co.za/

I am seriously having trouble with overriding to Bootstrap and also adding my custom font. To add my custom Google font, I've tried this, but did not work;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in css

```
html{
font-family:"Roboto", "Arial";
font-size:20px;
font-weight:300;}
```

Here's the img that I cannot style;

```
    <section class="container">
    <img class="rounded-circle profile-pic" src="/resources/img/profile_pic.jpg" alt="">
    </section>
```

And the styling;

```
section img .profile-pic{
margin-left:150px;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try to add in Body

```
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
```

The `html` styles will apply to all document but it has very low precedence. it will work only until and unless their is not specified styles inside body. but in your case bootstrap added their own styles in body tag.

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thats why your style was not working

Comment: Thank you, it worked well! But I've used it for html tag in one tutorial. Still don't understand why and how it differs.

Comment: @Onur Explained

Comment: Dear Sanjeet, thanks for your explanation. But I am also having trouble to style elements like p and h1. I added id's to direct them, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Onur, In that case, there might be font is not downloaded or just check the styles in developer tools which styles are currently applied to p and h1

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "!important" with your custom CSS style to override any bootstrap styles. Also, CSS will always use the most specific style to style an element so if you put your styles in html{} it will be overridden by p{} h1{} etc. Remember that style sheets are cascading so any styles at the top will be overwritten by styling the same element below.

Comment: In relation to the above post, body is more specific than HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "!important" with your custom css style to override bootstrap css.

One more thing if you are using external custom css file than import after bootstrap css file.

See, below example for more.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<style>
  html{
    font-family:"Roboto", "Arial" !important;
    font-size:20px !important;
    font-weight:300; !important;
  }

  .h1-override{
      font-size:12px !important;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <div> testing bootstrap overriding </div>
    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase h1-override">Konect</h1>
<p class="text-center">Technology & Data Management Specialists</p>

 <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">without custom style</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But I still cannot use my styles for h1 and p. Could you also check it? I must doing something wrong.

Comment: Dear Kaushik, unfortunately, I couldn't manage to override on h1 element, instead I wrapped it as p and styled it. Anyways, thanks for your interest and help. Wish you the best!

Comment: @Onur i already override H1 tag in above answer , did you see output?

Comment: Now, I am having another trouble on another element. (Edited in my question)  I think I am missing a really fundamental point. I checked the order of link of my stylesheet and bootstrap's (mine is coming right after bootstrap's), I am trying to specify the elements due to css element hierarchy. But gosh, I am still unable to override my own styles in a comfortable way.